# How to explode php result

Tags: php

I'm sorry for bad English.

First, this is my code:

```
$cok = $get->signup("4110069061");
echo $cok;
```

And the result is:

```
kKIR4cGstfwkl9obhc58gaozugo5k7yc9vmm77p3:4110069061.c6384ef.821b51c9fbe54980a7a4e45847767079:4110069061:13090485
```

My questions is:

How to explode this delim ":"

I want to make this result like this:

Session:

> kKIR4cGstfwkl9obhc58gaozugo5k7yc9vmm77p3

Token:

> 4110069061.c6384ef.821b51c9fbe54980a7a4e45847767079

ID:

> 4110069061

MID:

> 13090485

Can you understand? Please help me

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the code where you call `explode()` function ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I just have

public function getContents(){
public function signup($id_ig){

Comment: A simple search for "php explode string" would have answered this...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did *no* research and could have easily found the function necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cokArray = explode(":", $cok)
```

You will get an array which will be spited.

Comment: so how to get the session id mid separately?

Comment: This should do the trick. But i suggest you use a different more **uncommon** delimiter, to avoid instances where you explode the wrong part. Something like `-@-` or similar.

Comment: $cokArray[0] will contain session id, $cokArray[1] will contain Token

Comment: @Bokul thank you so much :)